# Using EmberJS and Oauth2, how can I modify the default route after invalidation?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, oauth-2.0, invalidation, ember-simple-auth

My goal is to send the user to a different page/route other than the oauth default after invalidation. Currently the default is my root login page. How can I change this?

I have this logout code in app/controller/protected.js. 
Specifically the `.invalidate();` method is what I'm trying to modify.

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
    session: service(),

    actions: {
        invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();

        }
  }
});
```

This is my code in app/routes/protected.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't Ember Simple Auth doing a full page refresh on invalidation by default?

Comment: try `this.transitionTo('your.target.route.here')`